# Can metal electrical panels have a non-rectangular or squared shape?

Tags: enclosure, panel

Standard metal electrical distribution panels are rectangular or square shaped boxes.

Is there any standard - IEC, NEC, etc.- contraindicating  the manufacturing of a custom shaped box for an electrical panel, i.e. with round, elliptical or any other shapes?

Comment: Why, do you want one in a heart shape?

Comment: I think the word "contraindicating" is misapplied here - it's a medical term isn't it?

Comment: There won't be a standard for any other shape because standards have to be widely applicable. There's no fundamental reason why you couldn't make a custom panel that meets code in all other respects than the dimensional drawing. Except economics. But if a round panel saves a kilogram on an aircraft, you can bet they'll make a round panel.

Comment: Determining if there is a contraindication for something is rather difficult. There are practical reasons that you will not find anything but a square box for distribution, but there are cylindrical boxes for other electrical purposes, If you have a specific reason for wanting such a box this might be a legitimate question here. If this is a hypotetical question, it is off topic. This forum is for specific electrical engineering design and theory questions.

Comment: The electrical code gurus ofer on [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions) might have a better idea.

Comment: @SolarMike Perhaps. A round shape one, for architectural reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In many countries electricity distribution boxes need a type certification. Other boxes are illegal. Type certification can be made only in an authorized laboratory. And the manufacturer needs another certificate to be able legally sell type certified products. The manufacturing process is auditioned every year. This all costs time and money.

There are all kind of other markings such as CE, which in Europe is manufacturer's way to claim "this product fulfills standards". I have kept in my hands from far east imported (=ordered from a webshop) CE marked equipment and their CE marks were not worth more than the ink they contained. There's a good reason to demand actual certificates.

Actual certificates are traceable, authorities keep lists of certified products and what is manufacturer's certification status - does he still have a right to sell that certified product.

I guess nobody hasn't wanted to spend the time and money that type certification needs for obscure products such as lung or liver shaped electricity distribution boxes. A multi-billion dollar information campaign maybe could change the situation by successfully guiding a remarkable amount of people to want non-rectangular electricity distribution boxes.

Think about famous film stars, popular musicians and good looking celebrating sporty young people dancing and presenting their new liver shaped distribution boxes as their most valuable thing for the good living. Coca Cola has done it with their product - why not anyone else?

Comment: Worked for cal king beds!

Answer (score 1):

Distribution panels are designed as part of a wiring system. They are standardized (by NEC, etc) in various sizes to make it easier to source from multiple vendors, for architects and engineers to design with them, and for electricians to install them safely using specific guidelines.

They are engineered to have adequate routing space for cabling, standoff space for busses and breakers, as well as a host of other concerns. Their final shapes reflect typical building practices (such as mounting between 16” studs) and compatibility with field wiring (conduit, ducting, etc.)

I suppose that it would be possible to design a box with an alternative shape that could meet basic safety and wiring density requirements. But then comes the question, how would you install it in a building? You need to address that too, and certify it as a system. Then you’d need to convince architects and engineers to use it. Not impossible, but worth it as a viable business? I couldn’t say.